# Recording file upload using Gatling

Tags: gatling

When I tried to record file upload and run it using Gatling, there was no error reported but, the file was not uploaded. It's a JSF application which uploads file using a page inside iframe. I am using Gatling 2.0.1. When I checked scala script generated by Gatling it show the followng code:

```
.exec(http("request_213")
        .post("""/App/page/upload.jsf""")
        .headers(headers_213))
```

Comment: Is it known issue with version 2.0.1? I found some of the calls triggered from page inside iframe fails to record with Gatling recorder. Are you sure that this is the problem with version? One reason why we don't upgrade is that the existing scripts behaves different in latest version.

Comment: I'm sure of nothing. I'm just saying you're using an old version of an open source project, and no open source project maintainer will bother investigating a possible issue on an old version.

Comment: ok, thanks! let me check with the latest version.

Comment: Have you tried this in Gatling 2.1.x ?